# Magento 2 : Update url to domain

Tags: magento2, url, base-url, domain

I'm using an Instance of Ubuntu 16.04 lts on Google to run a store, but I'd like to point to my domain.
Wich line on Apache2 should I update? [image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to update your `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` paths in `core_config_data`.

Then clear the cache by below command.

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/page_cache
```

Also you may also need to point your virtual hosts to current domain.